# Switching automatically from X11 to wayland in RHEL 8

Tags: linux, rhel, x11, gnome-shell, wayland

I'm executing a shell script inside profile.d, which needs **x11** as the default gnome-session. It works fine when login into system as **USER1**, but the **XDG_SESSION_TYPE** is shifting from **x11** to **wayland** when I try to switch user to **USER2** as a result not executing my script in profile.d. I've removed the comment for the line **Wayland=false** from the ***custom.conf*** located in ***/etc/gdm/*** to make **x11** as default **XDG_SESSION_TYPE**. Can anyone help with making **x11** as  default for the second logged in user as well!?